# How to convert long string into a dictionary by splitting on line breaks and colons

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have the following string that I have created in python:

```
metadata = """Passengerid: string
Name: string
sex: categorical
Fare: numeric
Fareclass: numeric"""
```

I would like to create a for loop that unpacks this string and creates a dictionary.

My desired output would be:

```
dct = 
{'Name': 'string',
'sex': 'categorical',
'Fare': 'numeric',
'Fareclass': 'numeric'
}
```

My instinct to get started is something like:

```
metadata.split('\n')
```

Which would yield the following list but is not creating anything that could be obviously turned into a dictionary:

```
['Passengerid: string',
 'Name: string',
 'sex: categorical',
 'Fare: numeric',
 'Fareclass: numeric']
```

Comment: why you don't want passengergrid in your dict? is there a reason?

Comment: How did you create that string? Can't you directly turn it into a dictionary?

Comment: This is asking a lot of questions in one. Try splitting it up into smaller parts. I doubt anyone will search for this exact same problem, so it is unlikely to be useful to people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This oneliner should work for you:

```
{x.split(':')[0].strip():x.split(':')[1].strip() for x in metadata.split('\n')}
```

Output:

```
{'Passengerid': 'string',
 'Name': 'string',
 'sex': 'categorical',
 'Fare': 'numeric',
 'Fareclass': 'numeric'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
metadata = """Passengerid: string
Name: string
sex: categorical
Fare: numeric
Fareclass: numeric"""

metadata = [tuple(m.replace(' ', '').split(':')) for m in metadata.split('\n')]
metadata_dict = {k:v for (k, v) in metadata}
```

[Update] Alternative approach by Rabinzel:

```py
metadata = """Passengerid: string
Name: string
sex: categorical
Fare: numeric
Fareclass: numeric"""

metadata_dict = dict(tuple(map(str.strip, string.split(':'))) for string in metadata.split('\n'))
```

Comment: You should probably trim rather than removing ASCII spaces anywhere in the strings.

Comment: `dict(tuple(map(str.strip, string.split(':'))) for string in metadata.split('\n'))` ...with strip it is propably the better approach. you can add it to your answer if you want.

Comment: added ✔️ I gave you credit tho. good tweak

Answer (score 0):

using the input data from metadata (triple quoted string) we can do:

```
my_dict = {}
for line in metadata.splitlines():
    k, v = line.split(":")
    my_dict.update({k: v})
```